# Clean output from IP like ifconfig gave

Tags: ip, ifconfig

Is there a way to get a clean/well formatted output from ip?

I know I'm still learning to us it but compared to what ifconfig used to print 'ip a' is just a mess and takes far longer for your eye to pick out whatever you're actually looking for.

Comment: Not that I am aware off. It's a nice command but it's output is crap if you are used to ifconfig. You can add the -c switch to colour the output, which makes it slightly easier to read.

Comment: You can clean or format the output with tools like sed, awk, perl, what do you want it to look like ?

Comment: Thanks @nobodyspecial, colour does help a bit actually

Maybe it's formatting will improve in future releases

Comment: this. talk about regressing. route tables are even worse.